# Use “There’s” with Plural Nouns

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I hear a lot things like:

> **There's tons** of papers.

Is this acceptable?

Related:

[*There's* with plural nouns - Redlinels](https://www.redlinels.com/theres-with-plural-nouns/)

By the way, what about a contraction **there're**?

Comment: There's heaps of (informal) situations in which *there's* is used with plural nouns. *There're* is also perfectly fine.

Comment: It's a perfectly normal part of informal speech for me and millions of other English speakers. I wouldn't use it in a formal situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we use "there is" for plural nouns?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/can-we-use-there-is-for-plural-nouns) Also [There's vs There are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/theres-vs-there-are) and [The use of “there is” and “there's”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267343/the-use-of-there-is-and-theres) and [There's vs there're](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168656/theres-vs-therere), among others.

Comment: Yes, thanks. (15 characters)